# How to change `sourceMappingURL` in parcel js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bundler, parceljs

How to manually set the path of `//# sourceMappingURL` inside the created `bundle.js`? Parcel currently creates a wrong path to the `bundle.js.map`.

**Parcel config:**

```
"scripts": {    
  "watch:js": "parcel watch ./src/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
}
```

**Current Behavior:**

```
 ~ bundle.js ~    

//# sourceMappingURL=/bundle.js.map
```

**Expected Behavior:**

```
~ bundle.js ~    

//# sourceMappingURL=/js/bundle.js.map
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple workaround is to add the following flag to your call to `parcel`, which will make the source-map URL relative to the JS file it maps, rather than an absolute.

```
--public-url ./
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1869#issuecomment-411578215) for more information.